# Desktop Window Manager always uses high CPU

Tags: windows-server-2012

My server has a problem about desktop window manager process in window server 2012 R2 64 bit. It always takes 10-20% CPU in anytime. This happened 2 week ago. Before that then, this process was normal. Please guide me how to troubleshoot or fix this.

This is screenshot:

[image]